# Layered navigation: Show more / less

Tags: layered-navigation

I'm trying to apply this code snippet (http://jsbin.com/binarenimi/edit?html,js,output) to my layered navigation with no success..
Where I'm wrong?

```
    <ol class="term-list">
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <li class="term-item ">
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
        <?php  
            $url = $_item->getUrl();
            $onclick = "ajaxFilter('".$url."')";
            echo '<a class="ajaxLayer"  onclick = "'.$onclick.'" >'. $_item->getLabel() . '</a>';
         ?> 
        <?php else: echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('ol.term-list').each(function(){
  if( $(this).find('li').length > 3){    
    $('li', this).eq(2).nextAll().hide().addClass('toggleable');
    $(this).append('<li class="more">Tutti</li>');    
  }
  $(this).on('click','.more', toggleShow);
});


function toggleShow(){
  var opened = $(this).hasClass('less');  
  $(this).text(opened ? 'Tutti' : 'Riduci').toggleClass('less', !opened);    
  $(this).siblings('li.toggleable').slideToggle();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `$` sign, it's used by Prototype.

Replace every `$(...)` in your code with `jQuery(...)`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('ol.term-list').each(function(){

        if( jQuery(this).find('li').length > 3){    
           jQuery('li', this).eq(2).nextAll().hide().addClass('toggleable');
           jQuery(this).append('<li class="more">Tutti</li>');    
        }
        jQuery(this).on('click','.more', toggleShow);
    });

});
```

Comment: It works! There's only a little problem: sidebar (also other content) is loading very slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this cause an issue. but try script inside document ready. Also make sure you have `jQuery.noConflict()` in your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
$('ol.term-list').each(function(){
  if( $(this).find('li').length > 3){    
    $('li', this).eq(2).nextAll().hide().addClass('toggleable');
    $(this).append('<li class="more">Tutti</li>');    
  }
  $(this).on('click','.more', toggleShow);
});
});

function toggleShow(){
  var opened = $(this).hasClass('less');  
  $(this).text(opened ? 'Tutti' : 'Riduci').toggleClass('less', !opened);    
  $(this).siblings('li.toggleable').slideToggle();
}
</script>
```

Comment: It does not work also adding jQuery.noConflict(); in the script

Comment: is it showing any js error in console?

Comment: Yes... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null

Comment: Not sure what conflict in your case. you can use https://github.com/eyemagine/Magento-LayeredNavLimit extension for your requirement.This might be help you.

Comment: i am using above your code it's working fine but if we have 2 or more attrribute value than it's not working proper.